# Download a zip file using Restful services

Tags: java, rest, download, zip

Im trying to create and download a zip file in java using restful service. But its not working for me. Please find the code below:

```
        @GET
    @Path("/exportZip")
    @Produces("application/zip")
    public Response download(@QueryParam("dim") final String dimId,
            @QueryParam("client") final String clientId,
            @QueryParam("type") final String type,
            @Context UriInfo ui) {
        System.out.println("Start");

        ResponseBuilder response = null ;

        String filetype = "";

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("u")){
            filetype = "UnMapped";

        }else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("m")){
            filetype = "Mapped";

        }
        try {

            byte[] workbook = null;
            workbook = engineService.export(dim, client, type);

            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(workbook);

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filetype + "tmp.zip");

            int bufferSize = 1024;
            byte[] buf = new byte[bufferSize];
            int n = is.read(buf);
            while (n >= 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, n);
              n = is.read(buf);
            }

            response = Response.ok((Object) out);

            response.header("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment; filename=\"" + filetype + " - " + new Date().toString() + ".zip\"");

            out.flush();
            out.close();


        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("End");
        return response.build();
    }
```

This is giving me the following error:
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.io.FileOutputStream, and Java type class java.io.FileOutputStream, and MIME media type application/zip was not found

Comment: Why are you setting the FileOutputStream as the response body?

Comment: @Gimby You are right. I removed that bit and i just passed the byte array to response as Response.ok((object) workbook). And the zip file was dowloadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't added MIME type of your response .  Your browser will be confused while processing this response. It needs response content type. To set response content type  for your response, add following code ,

```
          response.setContentType("application/zip");
```

after

```
          response = Response.ok((Object) out);
```

thanks.

Comment: Okay, but this error is generated by the server, not the browser.

Comment: Consider using MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.