# In Rest API, need to construct ZIP and download to client system

Tags: java, rest, file, download, zip

I have a REST API, which need to :
1. Create a few Json files from objects
2. Zip all of them
3. Download to client system - whoever is accessing the URL.

I am able to do step 1 and 2, but on doing step 3, it is downloading to my server, but not to client.
Currently i am trying in my local, Later this code moves to AWS, not sure there also it will download into the server or client local:

Code for step 3:

```
public void downloadZip(String zipFileName)
{
    File file = new File(zipFileName);
    if(!file.exists()){
        System.out.println("file not found");
    }

    OutputStream out = null;
    try
    {
        out = new FileOutputStream("test_"+zipFileName);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int length;
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        in.close();
        out.flush();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You code is just reading a file and writing it to another file

Comment: Have a look at https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-servlet-download-file-example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a zip file using Restful services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057566/download-a-zip-file-using-restful-services)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using content type `application/zip`.

```
 if(file.exists()){
        byte[] arr = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentLength(arr.length)
                        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/zip")
                        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + file.getName())
                        .body(arr);
} else {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
}
```

Comment: Is this a `Spring` solution?

Comment: @Scary, yes, it is :-)

Comment: @Scary, I just found it is duplicated question. Flagged it already ;-)

Comment: Yeah, but I prefer your answer, but wish it had pointers for using without `Spring`

Comment: Tried this,it is posting the whole content of a zip file in the response postmn.
size constraint, removed non reqd line



public ResponseEntity ZipDocuments(String orderId)
    {

        String fileName ="od.zip";
        File file = new File(fileName);
        try
        {
            byte[] arr = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().contentLength(arr.length).header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/zip")
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + file.getName()).body(arr);

Comment: This is working fine if REST API is called from browser, but if it is from postman, it is not working as expected, it is posting whole content in the response, that to some special chars.

Comment: @htpvl This is working fine in browser(downloading fine), but if i call the same REST API from postman it posts whole zip data @ postman (shows as junk data).

Comment: @vasu, if you are using postman to test your API, click `Send and Download` button to save your downloaded file to hard disk. This button is hidden under `Send` button

Comment: @htpvl, Thanks for all the help.It works with 'Send and Download', but as most of the users select 'Send'  at least first time 'Send' - is it possible to download as part of 'Send' button.

If not, at least I dont want to display all the junk characters as part of response, is there a way?